# Calling worker from class in javascript

Tags: javascript, class, function, object, worker

In my game, I have a character class:

```
var NPC = function(isometry,timer,canvas,tile,tileMap,scrollPosition,
grid,spritesheet, r1, c1, currentHero, hh, hw,index) {

this.index = index;   
....
NPC.prototype.w = new Worker('astar.js');

this.w.onmessage = function(e) {

//process worker results, 'index' is strongly needed
// e is data from worker
//it draws path for the character on the common tileMap:

tileMap[e.data[i].x][e.data[i].y] = index;
}
```

Then in main program I create two objects of that class:

```
var protagonist = new NPC(.....,0);
var char1 = new NPC(.....,10);
```

The problem is that they draw path with the same index = 10.
I tried:

1. to use this.index instead, but it turns undefined in the this.w.onmessage
2. call it "NPC.prototype.w.onmessage = function(e) {"  - the same story
3. Declare separate function:

   `NPC.prototype.wonmessage=function(e) {....}`
   `this.w.onmessage = this.wonmessage();`

`Error: "e is undefined".`

What should I do to send all the data correctly to the function?

Comment: Why is your worker on the prototype, shared (but overwritten) for all instances?

Comment: Maybe I just don't understand how to properly call it. I wished to have a separate process for each NPC.

Comment: I guess you actually have separate workers, but you still should change it to `this.w = new Worker`. Btw: What is that `i` variable in your message handler?

Comment: >>What is that i variable in your message handler?
Worker returns an array **e** = path on the tileMap. Then I draw it on the map and make my characters move on it square by square. They find their way checking nearest squares for their number, index.

Comment: So, `i` is the counter of your loop through the path array? OK.

Comment: Thank you, changing to `this.w` helped.